# How to import a C++ project into Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 RC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to import [this C++ project built with Visual Studio 2005](http://dm.kaist.ac.kr/jaegil/sources/movebank.tar.gz) into my Visual Studio Professional 2013 RC. As a newbie to the Visual Studio Series Software, I have no idea how to make it work.

The folder structure is as follows:

[image]

- Inside `bin`, there is file that has no extension called "param".
- Inside `include` are all the `.h` header files.
- Inside `traclus` are all the `.cpp` files.

You can always go to [here](http://dm.kaist.ac.kr/jaegil/sources/movebank.tar.gz) to find out what the folders contain.

**How may I run it in my Visual Studio?**

Comment: Why don't you just try opennig it in  2013? It should convert automatically.

Comment: @Farticle Pilter it would be great if you could tell us how you got it to work, if it ever did.